# Getting the Doctrine 2 ORM to hydrate objects with a custom query against a table with joins

Tags: postgresql, orm, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

### What I'm trying to do:

Execute a query with a haversine calculations against a table that also joins to other tables

### What's going wrong:

The associations at the ORM level aren't working/hydrating properly with the approach I'm attempting, it would seem

### The Details

I feel like if I cut and past every related bit of code, this question will become *huge* so I'm going to attempt to keep it to the relevant stuff.

First, here's the association mapping for the primary table being queried, which is **issue**

```
/**
 * @var IssueType $type
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IssueType")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $type;
```

*Note: There are actually four other associated tables, but the one above is "failing first" so I'm hoping that if I can solve the problem for this one, I can do it for the rest*

Now, working directly from [this article](http://www.wjgilmore.com/blog/entry/the_power_of_doctrine_2s_custom_repositories_and_native_queries) and taking some tips from [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/native-sql.html), I'm trying to pull data from the **issue** table within a specified geographic radius. But, unlike the example in the article, my data is not flat in a single table.  Enter my custom finder in my `IssueRepository` class:

```
public function findNear( $em, $point, $radius=1 )
{
  $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();

  $rsm->addEntityResult('MyBundle:Issue', 'i');
  $rsm->addFieldResult('i', 'id', 'id');
  $rsm->addFieldResult('i', 'title', 'title');
  $rsm->addFieldResult('i', 'detail', 'detail');
  $rsm->addFieldResult('i', 'lat', 'lat');
  $rsm->addFieldResult('i', 'lng', 'lng');

  $rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('MyBundle:IssueType' , 't', 'i', 'type');
  $rsm->addFieldResult('t', 'name', 'name');

  $query = $em->createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT i.*
          , ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( i.lat ) ) *
            cos( radians( i.lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
            sin( radians( i.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
          , t.name as type_name
       FROM issue i
       LEFT JOIN issue_type t
         ON i.type_id = t.id
      GROUP BY i.id, t.name
     HAVING ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( i.lat ) ) *
            cos( radians( i.lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
            sin( radians( i.lat ) ) ) ) < ?
      ORDER BY distance"
    , $rsm
  );

  $query->setParameter( 1, $point->lat );
  $query->setParameter( 2, $point->lng );
  $query->setParameter( 3, $point->lat );
  $query->setParameter( 4, $point->lat );
  $query->setParameter( 5, $point->lng );
  $query->setParameter( 6, $point->lat );
  $query->setParameter( 7, $radius, Type::INTEGER );

  return $query->getResult();
}
```

It's a bit messy right now, but I'm just trying to get this to work. The returned data from this query fails as soon as I attempt to pull an associated `IssueType` from an `Issue` object.

```
foreach ( $issues as $issue )
{
  // Fails, since Issue::getType() returns NULL
  echo $issue->getType()->getName();
}
```

This results in a

> "Call to a member function getName() on a non-object"

error.

Now, I don't know the internals of Doctrine2 very well, so I don't know how this ResultSetMapping-based query differs from the queries I normally execute via the ORM.

Can anybody shed some light?

### Versions

- PHP: **5.4**
- PostgreSQL: **9.1**
- Symfony: **Symfony 2.1**
- Doctrine: **2.3**

Answer (score 1):

probably (but I'm not sure) you have to describe the "meta column"

```
$rsm->addMetaResult('i', 'type_id', 'type');
```

Comment: I added this but it yields the same result. I'm assuming order-of-operation is irrelevant so I placed that line right before creating the query.